# Inserting bold and regular text into word via macro - alternating issue

Tags: vba, ms-word, doc

I have a macro and one of the arguments is an array. For each element in the array, I add a row to the table, add the standard text "NOTE:" and then the array element text. This is the relevant part of the macro I am using:

```
Sub fill(..., notes)

    Dim tblNew As Table
    Dim rowNew As Row
    Dim celTable As Cell
    Dim intCount As Integer

    For Each element In notes
        Set tblNew = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
        Set rowNew = tblNew.Rows.Add
        tblNew.Cell(tblNew.Rows.Count, 1).Range.Select
        Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
        If Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone Then
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        Else
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
        End If
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="NOTE:"
        Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
        If Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone Then
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        Else
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
        End If
        Selection.TypeText Text:=element
    Next element

End Sub
```

Now this does add all the rows, and it does add the "NOTE:" and array element text part ok, the issue is with the bolding and underlining. I want the "NOTE:" to be bold and underlined, and the element text to just be plain. With the above macro, for the first row the "NOTE:" is bold/underline and text is normal, but for the next row the "NOTE:" is normal and the element text is bold/underline. The pattern alternates row to row. So this is the pattern (minus the underlining):

**NOTE:**

element text

Note:

**element text**

**Note:**

element text

...and so on. I've been playing around but can't get it to be the same for each row, why is it doing this alternating behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that `NOTE:` must be Bold+Underlined and the text following it must be Normal. If this is correct, please try the below code:

```
Dim tblNew As Table
Dim rowNew As Row
Dim celTable As Cell
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim Notes As Variant

For Each element In Notes
    Set tblNew = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
    Set rowNew = tblNew.Rows.Add
    tblNew.Cell(tblNew.Rows.Count, 1).Range.Select
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    With Selection.Range
        .Text = "NOTE:"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    End With
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    With Selection.Range
        .Text = element
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
    End With
Next element
```